# Create library tld for Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

i want to integrate in Redshift tld utilities defined here : https://github.com/barseghyanartur/tld

I think i have to create a module as it is explained here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

but i'm a newbie in python. How i can do that?